# How to define "unknown", "undefined", or "any" in hasura action

Tags: types, hasura, typegraphql, hasura-cli

I am creating a hasura action, where output can be an array of object but object can have any key value pair hence I want to keep the output of hasura action as "any"
can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Your action should be able to return the type `json`

```
type Mutation {
  action(arg1: String!): json!
}
```